# MacBook Pro the full-screen video displayed on an external monitor is being rotated 180 degrees

Tags: macbook-pro, display, video

A year ago, I was using an external monitor with my MacBook Pro and had to set the display rotation to 180 degrees for coding purposes. I've since changed monitors and reset the display rotation to 0 degrees. Everything appears to work fine, except for an unusual issue: whenever I attempt to watch a video in full-screen mode, the display rotates back to 180 degrees.

It seems like there might be some residual settings from my old setup that are not resetting correctly and are triggered during full-screen video playback. For now, I'm using theater mode as a workaround to avoid this issue, but I'd like to use full-screen mode.

Has anyone encountered this issue before or know a possible solution?

UPD.
Macpro Pro 14,
Apple M1
MacOS 13.0.1 (22A400)

the issue with full screen youtube video in chrome, firefox, youtube, full screen in QuickTime, VLC video files, sometimes even happens in games - so i used to play in windowed mode instead of full screen,

Comment: Which MacBook Pro?  What version of macOS?  Which videos?  YouTube, QuickTime, VLC, something else. Is it just one app or sll apps that play video?

Comment: Hi, Allan, updated my  issue

Comment: Does the problem occur in a new user account? This will tell you whether the problem is at the system or user level.

Comment: How did you change the rotation to 180° last time?

Comment: In addition to the new user account, try Safe Mode. If it stops there, it eill be related to something installed by you and not macOS.